# Magento multiple model in a single module

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I got a problem loading a second model handling a database with a module.
I got 1 controller `ValidateController` and 2 Models `Main` that extends `Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action` so I can't communicate with the database, and `Log` that communicates with the database.

When I call `$log = Mage::getModel('modulex/log');` it is fine it gives me the correct path for with `get_class($log)` but when I call `$log->load($params['id']);` it fails giving me this error:

```
Warning: include(Companyx/Modulex/Model/Resource/Main.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I don't see why it gives me this error, it should call `Resource/Log.php` that exists.

I show you my config.xml

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <modulex>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Companyx_Modulex</module>
                <frontName>modulex</frontName>
            </args>
        </modulex>
    </routers>
</frontend>
<global>
    <models>
        <modulex>
            <class>Companyx_Modulex_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>modulex_resource</resourceModel>
        </modulex>
        <modulex_resource>
            <class>Companyx_Modulex_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                    <log>
                            <table>companyx_modulex_logs</table>
                    </log>
            </entities>
        </modulex_resource>
    </models>
</global>
```

Thank you for your help !

==== EDIT SOLUTION ====
Create `/resource/Main.php` with this code

```
class Companyx_Modulex_Model_Resource_Main extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('modulex/log', 'id');
    }
}
```

My mistake was doing `$this->_init('modulex/main', 'id');`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message that you are receiving i reasonably clear, the resource model isn't found. Magento splits models into what is essentially a 2 layer system. One layer for dealing with business logic and the other layer for dealing with persistence / database interaction. When you call load on your model, this is proxied off to the resource model specified for you class. In your configuration this resource is being set-up as `Companyx_Modulex_Model_Resource_Main.php`, but you seemingly don't have a file in the location the class is supposed to be defined - `app/code/{codepool}/Companyx/Modulex/Model/Resource/Main.php`.

Comment: I've tried that but didn't work, but I didn't do the right thing I found out why and I'll edit my question with the solution. Thank you for your time.